# Implementing Search Button on my Keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, ime

I'm trying to implement a search button in place of the regular enter button on my inbuilt android keyboard. I tried doing:

```
resultView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
System.out.println("You searched for this!");
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

But the regular 'enter' button is still appearing. I do not want to use XML and i'm creating my UI completely on JAVA. What should i do? Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    EditText view = new EditText(this);
    view.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
    view.setSingleLine(true);
```

And you are good to go, you set **SingleLine** attribute to change the new line button "default behavior in multi-line editext" to search button .

Comment: ALL RIGHT!! Thank you very much! Will keep this in mind in the future as well! I'd vote you up, if i had enough reputation.. hehe

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set the imeOptions programmatically.   Try something like this:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
```

You might have to play around with the available options to get exactly what you want.

Comment: um i already did that actually.. if you see my question properly